# How to take photos with the same aesthetic of the attatched photo?

Tags: film, digital

[image: The following question is about this photo]

How can I go about taking photos like this one? I'm have no photography background but would like to get into it. I absolutely love the colors in this along with the grain and whole vibe of the photo. Is it film or digital, what camera can produce this quality, flashes, necessary stuff to do photography like this.

Comment: Can you better describe what you mean by "vibe"? See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions (and please also edit your title accordingly). Thanks!

Comment: Surely you would just take a blurry photo on a cheap camera and boost the contrast and lower the saturation afterwards...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the picture:

- It has typical heavy digital noise.
- It has a slow shutter speed.
- Nothing is really sharp.
- No flash has been used, the light comes from the original scene.

A very basic camera like a phone or compact would be able to do it with maybe the risk that they focus the picture correctly and end up too sharp. You may also lack iso control on the most basic gear and you may fail to bump up iso enough to get the noisy rendering you want.

For the overall colors tones you need a post processing software that will allow you to change the tone and colors rendering of the photo. Great ones would lightroom + the proper pluging or DxO + DxO Filmpack but I'am sure you could do that with much more basic software. Maybe instagram or something like that would do the trick. Be sure you disable all feature to remove noise then or your picture would look too clean.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from being blurry and noisy, this image also has a **high contrast**.  Its contrast curve is steep enough that its contrast was probably boosted later, for example in Photoshop.

To achieve this effect in photoshop, duplicate the current layer and set the top layer's blend mode to "Soft light".  You can repeat this multiple times for even greater effect or reduce the effect by lowering the top layer's opacity.

You may also need to slightly lower the **color saturation**.